# Django's on_commit difference in behavior when triggered via Django admin

Tags: python, django

I am trying to send api call via `transaction.on_commit` and it is kind of working but I am seeing a different behavior when I edit the model via Django admin vs when this code is triggered by some other means.

I have `UserRoles` model where I am calling

```
post_save.connect(sync_user_roles, sender=UserRole)
```

then in the `sync_user_roles(self, **kwargs)` I am calling

```py
transaction.on_commit(
    lambda: self._proc_user_role_sync(
        kwargs["instance"],
        pre_edit_users=[u.username for u in kwargs["instance"].users.all()],
        user_role=user_role,
        library_id=library_id,
    )
)
```

And I am just trying to print new users in the `_proc_user_role_sync`

```
def _proc_user_role_sync(
    self,
    instance: "models.UserRole",
    pre_edit_users: List[str],
    user_role: str,
    library_id: str,
):

    print(f"new users: {[u.username for u in instance.users.all()]}")
```

Whenever I edit user_roles via Django admin, I see the new state of db in the `_proc_user_roles_sync`, meaning the newly added user is showing up in the print statement. But whenever I trigger this code by making API call to backend, new user is not showing in the print statement, even though I can see it being stored in the db.

What exactly is causing this difference and how can I make sure that the newly added user shows up in the `_proc_user_role_sync` every time the code is triggered?